# Mac Paint Pro .paint file with layers to open in photoshop or other software

Tags: export, paint, photoshop, tiff, layer

I am attempting to open a .paint file from the Mac Paint Pro software (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/paint-pro/id592666912?mt=12) while maintaining the layers that were created.  In the below screenshot from the Mac Paint Pro software, you can see the colored rectangles on the image as layers shown in the column to the left.

[image]

I attempted to open it within Photoshop but it cannot open .paint files.  This software can export in a variety of formats.  However, most flatten the file into a single layer.

[image]

I attempted to export the .paint file as a .tiff to open in Photoshop since I had heard .tiff files can contain layers.  However, when I opened that .tiff file in Photoshop, the file was compressed into a single layer as with the other formats.  Here is the tiff file:
[image]

I am posting here to see if anyone has any suggestions on how to a.) open a .paint file containing layers in different software and/or b.) how to export a .paint file in a different format (options seen in the above picture) that should maintain the layers contained within the .paint file.  I assume this may be a software-specific question and I am open to any and all suggestions.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Unless there is a converter from .paint to .psd you may have to do this the long way: Save out each layer from paint as a .png file and then load them into Photoshop.  - The latter can be done with a script. And TIFFs can contain layers they're not the same a a Photoshop file

Comment: @GhoulFool ok good to know that there is a way to do it manually at least.  However, there is no clear way to export single layer files in Paint Pro (it exports the whole thing even if I have a single layer selected).  Do you have access to the photoshop upload script?  Also do you happen to know of a software that could open up a TIFF file with layers?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the images into a stack with this. There are [other scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026882/photoshop-script-how-to-add-image-to-a-layer#31051256) about. I think you can use the built in Image Processor to load a single image as a PSD. but I don't think you can add loads of images to layers.

The thing you need to watch for is make sure the images are exported at the same size - so they will stack together in the same place afterwards. if that makes sense.

```
// Description: Loads jpg/png/tif images into stack from one
// directory.
// Layers are renamed after the image
// layers are order alphabetically
//
// USE AT YOUR OWN RISK


// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF 


var baseDocCreated = false;
var baseImage = "";
var imageRes = 72;


var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select FOLDER to process");
if (inFolder != null)
{
  var fileList = inFolder.getFiles(/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|tif)$/i);
}

var num = fileList.length;

alert(num + " images to process into stack from\n" + inFolder);

// main loop starts here
for(var a = 0; a < fileList.length; a++)
{
  // load the frames one by one
  var doc = open(fileList[a]);

  var tempImage = app.activeDocument.name

  //create the base document to work with
  if (baseDocCreated == false)
  {
    imageW = app.activeDocument.width.value;
    imageH = app.activeDocument.height.value;
    imageName = "baseDoc";

    create_new_document(imageW, imageH, imageRes, imageName)
  }


  var moveTo = app.documents.getByName(baseImage);
  var moveFrom = app.documents.getByName(tempImage);
  move_image(moveTo, moveFrom)

  //close without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
  srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

  var rename = remove_extension(tempImage);

  app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = rename;
}


var nice = fileList[0].toString();
nice = remove_extension(imageName)
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = nice;


// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL



// FUNCTIONLAND
// --------------------------------------------------------


function create_new_document(w, h, res, aname)
{
  // alert(w + "\n" + h + "\n" + res + "\n" + aname)
  var docRef = app.documents.add(w, h, res, aname)
  baseImage = "baseDoc";
  baseDocCreated = true;
  srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
}


function move_image(to, from)
{
  //select the tempImage
  app.activeDocument = from;
  // move from tempImage to the baseImage
  var duplicateLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer.duplicate(to)
}

function remove_extension (str)
{
  return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```